# PHP system specific line endings behaviour

Tags: php

I was wondering what does it mean in layman's terms:

> pay attention to line endings - PHP uses a native function to parse the input, so a Mac file won't work on Unix

An example of what this means will help.

The text can be found here at http://php.net/get_meta_tags under parameters filename.

Comment: Basically it means that if you read a file on system A, but the file was created on system B, and A&B have different characters to signify the end of a line of text, that PHP function will fail as it's not "native-aware"

Answer (score 2):

Different operating systems use different characters to indicate a carriage return or line feed. Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) for more in depth information.

A Windows newline looks like this: `\r\n`, while a Unix newline appears as `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the concept of *[newline characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)* is extremely important to understand if you intend to work in multiple operating systems.  Different operating systems use different characters to represent a new line in a text file.  This particular description isn't quite accurate, though, since Mac files as of OSX *are* compatible with Unix.  However, Windows and older Mac files are indeed different.

Now what this quote means is that if your HTML file was created using one newline character (for instance, if it was created with Windows) and you are attempting to parse it on a system which uses a different newline character (for instance, a Linux box as a part of a LAMP stack), then it won't work.  It will have to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the problem with Mac line endings not working also.  You can enable the Unix line endings to work when reading a file by putting:

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
```